# Jackson conflicts in Apache Spark when used with Azure Java SDK

Tags: azure, scala, apache-spark, azure-synapse

Azure Synapse publishes the jars available at runtime [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-3-runtime). I am currently using Apache Spark 3.1 runtime.

My project also relies on the 1.4.0 version of azure-eventgrid as a dependency (which pulls in azure-core). I am getting the following errors when the job is deployed on Synapse.

The job functions fine locally, but not when deployed on Synapse.

> 21/11/29 17:38:00 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED,
> exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception:
> java.lang.LinkageError: Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.10.0,
> jackson-core=2.10.0, jackson-databind=2.10.0,
> jackson-dataformat-xml=2.12.5, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.12.5,
> azure-core=1.19.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts:
> https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot     at
> com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperShim.createXmlMapper(ObjectMapperShim.java:73)
> at
> com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.(JacksonAdapter.java:81)
> at
> com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.(JacksonAdapter.java:58)
> at
> com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter$SerializerAdapterHolder.(JacksonAdapter.java:113)
> at
> com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.createDefaultSerializerAdapter(JacksonAdapter.java:122)
> at
> com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.(IdentityClient.java:100)
> at
> com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClientBuilder.build(IdentityClientBuilder.java:139)
> at
> com.azure.identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.(ManagedIdentityCredential.java:70)
> at
> com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.getCredentialsChain(DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.java:129)
> at
> com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.build(DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.java:123)com.xxxxxxxxxxx.$anonfun$sendEvents$1$adapted(xxxxxxxGridSender.scala:25)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)  at
> xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.sendEvents(xxxxxx.scala:25)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)    at
> scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)    at
> scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)    at
> scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)  at
> scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)     at
> scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)  at
> xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.runner.xxxxxx.xxxxxx(xxxxxx.scala:82)     at
> xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx(xxxxxx.scala:61)     at
> xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.$anonfun$start$2(xxxxxx.scala:39)
> at
> scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.$anonfun$map$2(TraversableLike.scala:827)
> at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)    at
> scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)    at
> scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)    at
> scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)  at
> scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)     at
> scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)  at
> scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:826)
> at xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.x.xxxxx.xxxxxx.start(xxxxxx.scala:36)
> at xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx$.main(xxxxxx.scala:29)    at
> xxxxxx.xxxxxx.aiops.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.main(xxxxxx.scala)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:732)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.coercionConfigDefaults()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MutableCoercionConfig;
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.(XmlMapper.java:176)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.(XmlMapper.java:145)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.(XmlMapper.java:127)
> at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.builder(XmlMapper.java:218)
> at
> com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperFactory.createXmlMapper(ObjectMapperFactory.java:84)
> at
> com.azure.core.implementation.jackson.ObjectMapperShim.createXmlMapper(ObjectMapperShim.java:70)
> ... 45 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synapse has its own jars available as part of its [runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-3-runtime). The project dependencies need to be compatible with the jars available at the runtime.

There are two parts here:

1. Azure-core gets in Jackson dependency 2.12 series. Where as Apache Spark 3.1 is still on 2.10 series.
2. Azure-core is already available on the classpath of synapse (1.16.0). So any azure lib that one pulls in (which along with it, gets azure-core as a dependency), needs to be compatible with azure-core 1.16.0

To fix (1), I added the following:

```
object DependencyOverrides {

  /**
   * We do not have any direct dependency on jackson. Spark relies on 2.10 series and Azure-core sdk has dependency on 2.12.
   * In order to resolve conflicts, we explicitly provide the jackson dependency here to 2.10.5
   */
  val jackson = Seq(
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.10.0",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.10.0",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.10.0",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.10.0",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat" % "jackson-dataformat-xml" % "2.10.0",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype" % "jackson-datatype-jsr310" % "2.10.0",
  )

  val others = Seq(
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "27.0-jre"
  )

  val all = jackson ++ others
}
```

And override the above dependency in SBT:

```
dependencyOverrides ++= DependencyOverrides.all
```

To fix (2), Additionally add related jars in `others` above:

```
  val others = Seq(
    "com.azure" % "azure-core" % "1.16.0",
    "com.azure" % "azure-core-http-netty" % "1.6.2",
    "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "27.0-jre"
  )
```

In my case, adding azure-core was not just sufficient. Had to add, azure-core-http-netty and guava as well.