# how we can upload parquet file in azure blob storage using spark and scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage

```
 val input_blob_path = "Enter input azure blob path here"
    val output_blob_path = "Enter output azure blob path here"
    val storageAccountName = "Enter_Your_Storage_Account_Name"
    val storageKeyValue = "Enter_Your_Storage_Account_Key"
    val containerName = "Enter_Your_containerName"

    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("WriteDataToAzureBlob")
      .config(
        s"fs.azure.account.key.${storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net",
        storageKeyValue)
      .getOrCreate()

    parqDF.write.parquet("wasbs://${containerName}@{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${output_blob_path}")
```

I am using this code to write in blob storage but it's now working for me.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What do you mean by "it's not working for me"?

Comment: the code I am using is not  helping me to write the parquet file in blob storage

Comment: Any exception? Log?

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem i am getting this exception

Comment: any dependency we have to add in build.sbt??

Comment: Try adding: org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-azure:version

Comment: hey nir thanks for dependency but i am still getting this error scala module 2.13.2 requires jackson databind version >= 2.12.0 and < 2.13.0 in scala

Comment: Hi there, do you have any working example with Scala sbt project for writing, listing, updating blobs in a container in azure?

Answer (score 0):

For the error:

> scala module 2.13.2 requires jackson databind version >= 2.12.0 and <
> 2.13.0 in scala

- Try to remove old dependencies of Jackson and upgrade the plugin or
  added 2.12.0 series
- All of Jackson packages that Azure SDKs use , you may need to pin
  each of them to a specific version and their version number  set to
  the same one as of Spark.

OR

- Try to add a different com.fasterxml.jackson.core dependencies
  version as per error and  then you may need to override them explicitly.

  ```
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.12.5"
  ```

See 1.  [scala - Jackson conflicts in Apache Spark when used with Azure Java SDK - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70738081/jackson-conflicts-in-apache-spark-when-used-with-azure-java-sdk)

2. [Maven Repository: azure-core-serializer-json-jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-core-serializer-json-jackson/1.2.12)

**Other References:**

1. [Jackson compatibility issues GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/25732)
2. [scala -incompatible Jackson versions  -SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43841091/spark2-1-0-incompatible-jackson-versions-2-7-6)  , [Scala module 2.12.3 requires Jackson Databind version 3 -SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769492/scala-module-2-12-3-requires-jackson-databind-version-2-12-0-and-2-13-0-but)
3. [Manage Scala & Java libraries for Apache Spark - Azure Synapse
   Analytics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-scala-packages)